# procedural texture scaling

Tags: materials, procedural

Procedural texture scaling changes note picture A the flakes are bigger than flakes at B. Why this happens ?Texture should be identical!.

Note: A & B are two different objects with same material. Scale is also applied.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any textures in your object, which would be helpful to diagnose texture related issues, also your node tree screenshot is barely visible which doesn't help either.

Anyway, you seem to be using both *Generated* texture coordinates and *UV* texture coordinates, both of which can vary by object, the former depending on the geometry's actual dimensions, the later depending on its current UV layout.

Use either *Object* texture coordinates or *World* based ones if you have different scales across objects.